# Is there a easy way to group/Clusters Entries in one Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with several rows, that looks more or less like this.

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| ID | CustomerID | ProductType |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 1  | 1          | A           |
| 2  | 1          | A           |
| 3  | 1          | B           |
| 4  | 1          | B           |
| 5  | 1          | B           |
| 6  | 2          | A           |
| 7  | 2          | A           |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

> **ID** is just a auto_increment identity
> **CustomerID** is a unique Id for each customer
> **ProductType** Type of the specific Product

I need a `select`, that creates the following output:

**Desired result:**

```
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------------+
| ID | Cluster_ID  | Sub_Cluster_ID | CustomerID | ProductType |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------------+
| 1  | 1           | 1              | 1          | A           |
| 2  | 1           | 2              | 1          | A           |
| 3  | 2           | 1              | 1          | B           |
| 4  | 2           | 2              | 1          | B           |
| 5  | 2           | 3              | 1          | B           |
| 6  | 1           | 1              | 2          | A           |
| 7  | 1           | 2              | 2          | A           |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------------+
```

> **Cluster_ID** is a counter for a customer, that only counts up on a new `ProductType` *(so all rows for a Customer, with the same `ProductType`, have the same `Cluster_ID`)*
> **Sub_Cluster_ID** is a simple counter, that counts up the entries for a `ProductType` and Customer *(so all rows for a Customer, with the same `Cluster_ID`, have a incrementing `Sub_Cluster_ID`)*

I tried using [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but I could not get it to work

***Here some of my failed attempts:***

- This seems to works for the `Sub_Cluster_ID`, but not for the `Cluster_ID`.

  ```sql
  SELECT  [ID]
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CustomerID ORDER BY CustomerID, ProductType) Cluster_ID
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CustomerID, ProductType ORDER BY CustomerID, ProductType) Sub_Cluster_ID
      , [CustomerID]
      , [ProductType]
  FROM dbo.Table
  ```
- This seems is almost there, but the `Cluster_ID` is still not correct

  ```
  SELECT  [ID]
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CustomerID ORDER BY CustomerID) Cluster_ID
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CustomerID, ProductType ORDER BY CustomerID, ProductType) Sub_Cluster_ID
      , [CustomerID]
      , [ProductType]
  FROM dbo.Table
  ```

***Almost there:***
*(but the `clusterID` is still not matching the needed Output)*

```
 +----+------------+----------------+------------+-------------+
 | ID | Cluser_ID  | Sub_Cluster_ID | CustomerID | ProductType |
 +----+------------+----------------+------------+-------------+
 | 1  | 1          | 1              | 1          | A           |
 | 2  | 2          | 2              | 1          | A           |
 | 3  | 3          | 1              | 1          | B           |
 | 4  | 4          | 2              | 1          | B           |
 | 5  | 5          | 3              | 1          | B           |
 | 6  | 1          | 1              | 2          | A           |
 | 7  | 2          | 2              | 2          | A           |
 +----+------------+----------------+------------+-------------+
```

Is it anyway possible? Or do I need subqueries?

Comment: Do you care which row gets numbered which way in the sub_cluster? What about tomorrow? Should the numbering be stable, or do you not care if today the subs are numbers in ascending ID order and tomorrow they're ordered in ID descending order?

Comment: @CaiusJard great catch I didn't think about it, you are right, I would need a stable sort order. Is there something special to be watched for?

Comment: So, today ID 5 is getting sub **3**, but lets say I delete ID 4, tomorrow ID 5 will get sub **2** - it'll still be after ID 3 which is getting sub 1, but from yesterday to today it will have changed sub value. Are you concerned?

Comment: @CaiusJard Deletion/Id Updates are not happening, but new Items come every day. Would that be a problem?

Comment: I would say not, and in such a case look at Charlieface's suggestion to use the ID as the sort order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `DENSE_RANK` for this.

However, it makes no sense to partition and order by the same columns like in the other answer. So you can either use an arbitrary ordering for the `ROW_NUMBER`

```sql
SELECT
  ID,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ProductType) as Cluster_ID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, ProductType ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) Sub_Cluster_ID,
  CustomerID,
  ProductType
FROM table_name;
```

Or you can order by another column such as `ID`

```sql
SELECT
  ID,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ProductType) as Cluster_ID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, ProductType ORDER BY ID) Sub_Cluster_ID,
  CustomerID,
  ProductType
FROM table_name;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=512125e637e495c491d96083eecd33d2)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` for `Cluster_ID`:

```
select ID,
dense_rank() over(partition by CustomerID order by CustomerID, ProductType) as Cluster_ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CustomerID, ProductType ORDER BY CustomerID, ProductType) Sub_Cluster_ID,
CustomerID,
ProductType
from table_name;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6fc4baf6a1c013fd62dbe7fec0e0ced3)